# File sorting according to the pattern

Tags: bash, files, regular-expression

I am dealing with management of big number of filles having fixed structure of the name, in multi-column format separated by _:

```
3000_12_lig_cne_158.dlg
1300_10_lig_cne_983.dlg
4000_09_lig_cne_158.dlg
5000_09_lig_cne_158.dlg
7000_09_lig_cne_158.dlg
10V1_06_lig_cne_983.dlg
10V2_11_lig_cne_158.dlg
N000_12_lig_cne_158.dlg
M000_10_lig_cne_158.dlg
E000_10_lig_cne_158.dlg
```

So the first column can contain either four numbers (like 7000) or combination of the numbers and letters (like N000 or 10V1).

Using some bash routine I have to sort all of those filles according to the first column name, creating for each repertoire sub-directory matched the name of the first column. So for the list of the demonstrated filles totally 10 directories (3000, 1300, E000, M000, 10V1, 10V2 etc) should be created.

For the filles having only digital number in the first column I can use the following rouring, which uses regular expression in FOR loop to sort the filles.

```
for i in ${FILES}/[0-9]*_*.dlg        # match the filles containing only digits in the first column
do 
    j=${i##*/}               # strip the path off from beginning to last /
    mkdir -p $OUTPUT/${j%%_*}        # create dir with the name matching the first column of the file
    mv $i $OUTPUT/${j%%_*} # move the file to the corresponded directory
done
```

How I could modify it to match all of the demonstrated patterns of the first column ?

Comment: Can you use `????_*.dlg`?

Comment: just tested on small subset of filles, it seems that it works!! I am going to test on 20000 filles ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need four characters, use `?` for a single character four times:

```
for dlg in "$FILES"/????_*.dlg
```

Comment: note that it would also match on `xx_2_foo.dlg` or `+_+__.dlg` for instance.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` (your script is already in `zsh` syntax, not `bash` as you're not quoting your parameter expansions):

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc

zmodload zsh/files # makes mkdir and mv (and a few other file manipulation
                   # utilities) builtin to speed things up.

mkmv() { mkdir -p -- $2:h && mv -- "$@"; }

(
  cd -P -- "$FILES" &&
    zmv -P mkmv '([A-Z0-9](#c4))_*.dlg' '$1/$f'
)
```

Where `[A-Z0-9](#c4)` matches 4 of the English uppercase letters (and in `zsh`, them only, not the  `Ŕ`, `Æ`, , etc that other shells would typically include there) or decimal digits (and again, them only, not the `²`, , ... that `bash` for instance would include).

Note that your `[0-9]*_*.dlg` is *not* a regular expression, it's a shell wildcard, that matches on file names that start with one character in the `0` to `9` range (which in `bash` includes hundreds of characters in most locales), followed by any number of characters (`*`) followed by `_` followed by any number of characters followed by `.dlg`. The regexp equivalent would be `^[0-9].*_.*\.dlg$`.

Comment: thank you! could you specify what do you mean by "not quoting your parameter expansions" ? I mean that technically my script works very well but anyway If there are some errors I will be happy to fix it ...

Comment: @user3470313, in `bash` and POSIX shells, you need to quote parameter expansions unless you want split+glob applied to them. See for instance [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346) and all the other Q&A linked from there, or [the bash wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target)

Comment: Yes, I got that it is neccesary to use "$FILES"/????_*.dlg  rather then $FILES/????_*.dlg    BUT I've just done test and there were no difference between the both :-)

Comment: @user3470313, that all depends what characters your filename contains and the current value of `$IFS`. It will become clearer if you read the pages at the links I provided.

Comment: right, thank you! but general rule, that all variables (contained paths to files or elements of lists) should be double qted like "$FILES" , shouldn't it ?

Comment: @user3470313, yes, all word expansions (`$param`, `$((arith))`, `$(cmd)`...) should be quoted in list context unless you *need* split+glob to be applied to them.